# Is rkhunter still required and appropriate? Nothing seems to have been written on it since 2015. Thanks

Tags: security, malware, rkhunter

I want to use my Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla desktop for internet banking and making purchases.  Good digital hygiene is of course the first defence but i'd like to make sure that rootkits are thwarted as best i can.  Is rkhunter still my best bet?  Any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical of the value of "rootkit hunters" -- once upon a time, when rootkits were malicious versions of `/bin/ps` and `/bin/ls` they may have had value, but modern exploit kits modify the kernel internals directly. If secure boot is enabled on your system, you'll have some level of protection against persistent root kits.

You'd be better served by keeping up on security updates -- we publish new kernels roughly every three weeks, and almost every kernel update includes security fixes. We publish new browsers periodically and almost every browser update includes security fixes.

- `sudo apt install unattended-upgrades`

If openssh-server is installed on your systems, you can get very good security and usability gains by switching from password authentication to public key authentication.

- [Generate ssh keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)
- [Disable sshd password authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#disable-password-authentication)

Of course the usual advice about being careful of emails and email attachments applies, too.